# Creating in-line variable in field calculator of QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression

I create new field based on other fields. For example; if `"Field_A"` is smaller than `"Field_B"`, the value of the new field is `'A'`, otherwise it is `'B'`. So I want to create a new variable for this case within Expression area.

It's possible in QGIS 3 by means of `with_variable` function. But QGIS 2 doesn't have that function.

In QGIS 3:

```
# mn -> new variable
with_variable( 'mn',  min( "Field_A", "Field_B" ),
               if( @mn = "Field_A", 'A', 'B' ) )
```

or

```
with_variable( 'mn',  min( "Field_A", "Field_B" ),
               case when @mn = "Field_A" then 'A' else 'B' end )
```

In QGIS 2, I want to write something like that:

```
mn = min("Field_A", "Field_B")

CASE
WHEN mn = "Field_A" THEN 'A'
WHEN mn = "Field_B" THEN 'B'
END
```

I don't mean global or project variable, I'm asking to create a new variable to be used in Expression area scope.

How can I do that within Expression area in QGIS 2?

Comment: The with_variable() function is a new feature in QGIS 3. As far as I can tell there's no equivalent function in QGIS 2.